# Determining the source of the click event dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a set of buttons that are added dynamically. As the user keeps clicking the buttons, new buttons are added to the window. I am using a winforms. I am binding the onclick event of all these buttons to the same function. I am using the following code.

```
System.EventHandler myEventHandle= new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Clicked);
```

Once a new dynamic button is created I add the event handler with the following code:

```
b1.Click += myEventHandle;
```

Now in the function Button_Clicked() I want to get the Button which invoked this event. I want to disable this Button so that it cannot be clicked again and I want the name of the Button that was clicked as I want to do various actions depending on button name. I am newbie in C#.

This is what I have tried so far, but doesn't seem to work:

```
        Button b = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button;
        b.Font = new Font(b.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        Console.WriteLine(""+b.Name);
        b.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("" + b.Name);` console in winforms application?

Comment: Use `Debug.WriteLine(b.Name)` for debugging

Comment: Solved, another handler is enabling them. Figured it out. Sorry to bother u guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `Button_Clicked` method must look like

```
void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;//if sender is always a Button
  clickedButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Its not getting disabled. Tried it.

Comment: @sasidhar is it possible that you have some other code which enables button?

Comment: yes it seems so, sorry for bothering you all. Another handler is enabling them. Overlooked It sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Use the sender of the event

```
if(sender is Button)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    b.Enabled = false;
    ///something = b.Name;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Tried, when using `b.Name` it says `The thread '<No Name>' (0x1efc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: I would say `b.Enabled` (not `Enable`)

Comment: are you creating these buttons in a different thread? or using them across threads?

Comment: No as these buttons are clicked more buttons are added, actually within the same function I add more buttons.

Comment: None of the lines of code you've included I'd imagine to error (I presume its an error although exit code 0..) have you tried setting breakpoints